# sending hex bytes to serial in bash - strange output

Tags: shell, serial-port, hex, send

[image]I can send hex this way:

echo -en '\x10\x02\x06\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x9E\x09\x78\x06\x06\x26\x04\x0A\x02\x06\xD3\x03' > /dev/ttyUSB0

when I open a 2nd terminal for reading (cat < /dev/ttyUSB0) I only get some strange output. It is a square with number 15 in it. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you send binary data (using hexadecimal notation).  A *"2nd terminal"* could receive that data from that same device only if that serial port is configured for loopback.  You do not mention any such condition.  If there is a loopback in place, then you cannot expect a text interface (i.e. the shell) to display binary data from a terminal in canonical mode.

Comment: mhh, it seems like it is configured as loopback cause I get the correct number back. the "15" in that square is correct. But that square around is to much. I thought it is just a fault in the "format". maybe i have to tell the shell to show decimal instead of hex ?!? is there a way to do that?

Comment: *"the "15" in that square is correct."* -- How is that *"correct"*?  What does that correspond to in the data sent out?  *"is there a way to do that?"* -- Yes.  `cat` displays text.  `od` displays octal.  `od -x` displays hexadecimal.

Comment: It is a little bit difficult to explain. The device "answers" with different numbers. the answer "06" means "ok", the answer "15" not ok and so on...
"correct" means, when I get back the "15" oder "06", the the sring i sent was ok. the only thing that is "not correct" is the square around the "15" or "06". when I use od -x, I did not get the "06" or "15". It seems like "15" or "06" or not hex :-( mhh, strange thing -.-

btw: how can I save the output from "cat < /dev/ttyUSB0" to txt file? "(cat < /dev/ttyUSB0) >> test.txt" does not work

Comment: *"It is a little bit difficult to explain"* -- No, it shouldn't be.  You either have nothing connected, or there's a device connected, or there's a loopback.  You initially report nothing, then you claim that there is a loopback, and finally you admit that there is a mystery device to respond to commands.  It's only difficult because you are reluctant to provide the correct information to help clarify the issues.

Comment: i try to explain it again.there is only one device
connected.when i send something to the device, i always get a response.
the response i want to see in the console with cat</dev/ttyUSB0. the
response "06" and "15" are responses for a successful request. i get
the "06" ,but with the square around. i thought this is a hex number...
in a 2nd try i want to output everthing to a txt-file, cause maybe it is
only a fault by the console to show me the "06" in the right format .
that does not work with the code above. btw: i thought the devive has/is
a loopback because it sends some data back